# CSS gradient Multi-line for multi child element text not working

Tags: html, css, gradient

I'm creating a design theme for my project. For that I am using Webkit text gradients to apply gradient colors for multi line text. I want to spread/stretch gradient to the full height of the parent element.
But text gradients only works when text node is direct child of gradient element. And if i use multiple child element with in the parent element than gradient is not working.

To add some other functionality to text, i have to use child elements as wrapper. So each new line will have its wrapper element.

What can i do to make it work?

Example code:

```
#container span {
  background: -webkit-repeating-linear-gradient(top, #ff0000, #0000ff) !important;
  /* This background gradient might be move to `#container` style below? */  
  -webkit-background-clip: text !important;
  -webkit-text-fill-color: transparent !important;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-family: Arial;
  display: inline-block;
  font-size: 50px;
  
}
#container {
    width: 640px;
    background: black;
    /* background property should work with gradient */ 
    /* background: -webkit-repeating-linear-gradient(top, #ff0000, #0000ff) !important; */  
}
```

```
<div id="container">
  <span>This is a one line long text.</span>
  <span>This is a one line long text.</span>
  <span>This is a one line long text.</span>
  <span>This is a one line long text.</span>
  <span>This is a one line long text.</span>
  <span>This is a one line long text.</span>
</div>
```

JSFiddle Of Example Code: https://codepen.io/nishitbhatt/pen/ZEmQyEp

JSFiddle Of Working Text Gradient With One Child Element: https://codepen.io/nishitbhatt/pen/PoxZjZg

Comment: add break tag after each line and change display: inline-block to display: inline;
Please check this: https://codepen.io/sample1010/pen/abQdLJN is it what you want to do?

Comment: @VaibhavGidde Text of each line must be wrapped within span tag (Example code). 
But the text gradient effect should be similar to this codepen: https://codepen.io/nishitbhatt/pen/PoxZjZg (must stretched to parent height instead of applying in single line)